# Count cells/rows that contains specified string from all columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write query that would go through whole table and count cells which contains e.g. "1/23/20" but i have found only ways how to search one specific column. Is it possible to search all columns?

Comment: What is the table structure?
is it a single column with the date, are you sure its a string and not a date?

Comment: there is dozens of columns (number/id), their rows contains dates but i am not sure if i will use DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); Date date = new Date(); or ZonedDateTime.now() because of readability